# Can I factory reset a Kindle without interfering with another newer Kindle?

Tags: kindle, kindle-fire

Can you reset one kindle to factory reset, without it bothering a newer  kindle?

I would assume yes, because I can pick where to send my ebooks but I just want to be sure...

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You assume correctly, resetting one kindle will not have an effect on your other kindle device :)